# Duals In The Category Of Sets

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I know that the monoidal category $(\text{Set},\times)$ doesn't provide duals.  Is it meaningful in any way to ask how duals would look like if we forced them into existence there?  Is there a canonical way to equip a cartesian closed category with duals?

Would it make sense to assert that in such a category we would have rational cardinalities?  (Somehow this feels so natural to me.)

Comment: You could look at the free functor $F: \text{Set} \to \text{Vect}_k$, and try to make sense of what happens as the characteristic of $k$ approaches 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that what you mean by duals is, for each object $A$, a dual $A^\bot$ such that $\text{Hom}(A,B)\cong A^\bot\times B$ (natural in $B$). If you adjoined such duals to the category of sets, then for every set $A$ you'd have $1\cong \text{Hom}(A,1)\cong A^\bot\times 1$. If $1$ is to remain the monoidal unit, this gives $1\cong A^\bot$ for all $A$. That is, all the newly adjoined dual-sets would have to be isomorphic to singletons.  as a result, the required equation $\text{Hom}(A,B)\cong A^\bot\times B$ will fail most of the time.